# Was Eurystheus a lover of Heracles? Did Heracles have any other male lovers?

Tags: greek, hercules, demi-gods, love

In some versions of the 12 labors of Heracles, Eurystheus is a lover of Heracles and he undertook the 12 labors for Eurystheus' love. Did Heracles have any other male lovers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heracles had a number of male lovers. Plutarch's Dialogue sur l'amour (Eroticos) mentions that the number of Heracles' male lovers were beyond counting. Hence, the list of lovers presented here is incomplete (most probably):

- Abderus
- Admetus
- Adonis
- Corythus
- Diomus
- Elacatas
- Euphemus
- Hylas
- Iolaus
- Iphitus
- Jason
- Nestor
- Nireus
- Perithoas
- Philoctetes
- Phrix
- Sostratus

Nowhere it is mentioned that Eurystheus and Heracles were lovers, neigh, had feeling for each other. Hence the probability of Eurystheus being one of Heracles' lovers is ruled out.

<sub>sources:

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heracles#Men)

              [Hellenica](http://www.hellenicaworld.com/Greece/Ancient/en/AncientGreekScienceAndTechnology.html)</sub>